# Covariance of large matrix

Tags: python, matrix, bigdata, pca, covariance

I have a large Matrix (70000x784) that I want to compute the covariance Matrix (70000x70000) of. I tried using numpy.cov(), but I get a memory error because there are too many observations (and yes I am running a 62 bit Version of Python on a 62-bit computer).

I attempted to calculate the covariance Matrix using a nested for loop (which is really slow), but I know it's not correct because the resulting covariance Matrix is not symmetrical (X[i,j]!=X[j,i]).

Surely, there must be an easier and quicker way to do this?

Here is my attempt, where the input Matrix With Dimensions 70000x784 is X_scaled:

```
Xt = np.transpose(X_scaled)
aveRows = np.mean(Xt,axis=0)
for i, val in enumerate(X[:,0]):
    for j, val in enumerate(X[:,0]):
        cov_matrix[i,j] = np.mean((X_scaled[i,:]-aveRows[i])*(X_scaled[j,:]-aveRows[j]),axis=0)
    #increase cov_matrix by one row and one column:
        cov_matrix = np.lib.pad(cov_matrix, ((0,1),(0,1)), 'constant', constant_values=(0)) 
        print(cov_matrix.shape)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compute the mean and the covariance of a large matrix(300000 x 70000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371402/compute-the-mean-and-the-covariance-of-a-large-matrix300000-x-70000)